# How do we know the hyperbolic plane is 2 dimensional?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, curvature, low-dimensional-topology, dimension-theory-analysis

Consider a disk in the hyperbolic plane with radius $R$, the area of this circle is given by $2 \pi \sinh(R) = 2\pi \frac{e^{R} - e^{-R}}{2}$

Usually an argument that the disk is 2-dimensional goes by observing that area of a circle quadruples when the radius is doubled.

In the hyperbolic case the area FAR MORE than doubles when the radius is doubled. In fact it cannot even be polynomially bounded. It would appear our notions of dimension depend in a fundamental way on the curvature of the ambient space we are in.

So the question: how can we still conclude the hyperbolic disk is 2-dimensional?

Comment: My first thought is that if you have angles that means you have two distinct lines which intersect at a point. I think there should be a homeomorphism to $\mathbb{R}^2$ from there.

Comment: Alternatively, you're constructing the homeomorphism by covering the hyperbolic plane with circles from $\mathbb{R}^2$. Since the circles are two dimensional, so is the hyperbolic plane You already more or less did that.

Comment: Is there a way for someone living in the hyperbolic plane to intrinsically detect that though? like they just draw their own hyperbolic circles and start measuring areas and find a non quadratic scaling law, they then can be sure its hyperbolic space but whether its 2 dimensional, 3dimensional etc... is not clear yet. If we fall back on the coordinate definition then they say "well idk what space I live in but it needs 2 real coordinates to describe so its effectively 2 dimensional" and I guess that works

Comment: You don't need coordinates just lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many notions of dimension, and you are confusing a couple of them.